# Set individual positions for multiple geometries and then merge these geometries

Tags: javascript, three.js

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as BufferGeometryUtils from 'three/addons/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js';

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, innerWidth / innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

camera.position.z = 10; 


// create material and 2 sphere:
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } ); 
const sphere_geo1 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2, 32, 32 ); 
// sphere_geo1.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array([-5,0,0]), 3));
const sphere_geo2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2, 32, 32 ); 
 
// merge spheres and add merged to scene:
var merged_geo = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeGeometries([sphere_geo1, sphere_geo2], false);
const merged = new THREE.Mesh( merged_geo, material );  
scene.add(merged);
```

Before merging, I'm trying to set position to first sphere (say `x=-5`), and using for this `setAttribute('position')`, but if uncomment that line, `sphere_geo1` does not seem to appear in that position. What I'm doing wrongly?

I use **r161**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set position of geometry by `setAttribute('position'...)`, that can be problematic in merged geometry.

Try using `translate` method instead, then you moving entire geometry:

```
sphere_geo1.translate(-5, 0, 0);

//---or

merged_geo.translate(-5, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, `sphere_geo1.translate(-5, 0, 0);` is what I looked for.